# Where Are the Startup Settings when Running Elasticsearch 5.x as a Service?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch 5.x, changing settings in `etc/init.d/elasticsearch` does nothing. Where should I change the startup settings (not elaticsearch.yml) when running Elasticsearch 5.x as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch 5 installed through the Debian installer uses Systemd rather than init.d to autostart, so the config file for the service would be in

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service`

Additionally, the settings for the Java Virtual Machine (also started at startup time) are in

`/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`